# Access authentication object when request does not pass Spring security chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

What I'd like to achieve is a non-secured page (e.g. /index), but when authenticated it should have access to the authentication object to display the logged in user.

According to the Spring documentation, authentication objects are not available when not passing through the security filter chain:

> If you want to make use of the contents of the SecurityContext contents during a request, then it must have passed through the security filter chain. Otherwise the SecurityContextHolder will not have been populated and the contents will be null.

But to disable page security, the security filter is disabled:

```
<http pattern="/index" security="none"/>
```

> Similar to filters=”none”, this will also completely disable the Security filter chain for that request path – so when the request is handled in the application, Spring Security features will not be available.

I also can't use `<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" />`, since this gives permission to all **authenticated** users. Since the `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` will throw an `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException` when no authentication object is found.

As a newbie to Spring Security, how can I construct a non-secured page which does have access to the SecurityContext? (Using Spring Security 3.2.9 with XML configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` which will create and assign an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` instance to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()` when no user is logged in. Thus you will not get `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException` and can do a simple `instanceof` operation to check whether a User is logged in or Anonymous.

```
<bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="key" value="anonymousUser"/>
    <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</bean>

<http pattern="/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll"/>
    <custom-filter ref="anonymousAuthFilter" position="ANONYMOUS_FILTER" />
</http>
```